# How to add additional label in the middle of each bar using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to add the percentage value in the middle of the graph.

**Currently, I have the following:** 
[image]

**I would like to make my charts something like that:** 
[image]

So how can I add this percentage value or any kind of text in the middle of the bar using chartJS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/) as follows:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "X",
        data: [15, 8, 12],
        backgroundColor: "red"
      },
      {
        label: "Y",
        data: [7, 6, 15],
        backgroundColor: "blue"
      },
      {
        label: "Z",
        data: [6, 12, 10],
        backgroundColor: "green"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, context) => {
          let total = context.chart.data.datasets[context.dataIndex].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
          return Math.round(1000 / total * value) / 10 + '%';
        },
        color: 'white'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="5"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's displaying an error if I have data like `data: [15, 8, 12, 39]`

Comment: Please show more of you code and the detailed error message, otherwise it's almost impossible to help.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I fixed it different way.